# Getting notified when a client is connected to the server in java

Tags: java, websocket, activemq-classic, stomp

I am learning how to make realtime applications in java.I am using activemq which uses stomp  as a wired format to send WebSockets messages between the WebSocket server running within the ActiveMQ broker and the Web browser.

Its easy to notify the client that he/she is connected to the server but is it possible to notify a listening java server program that a client has connected to the server?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveMQ adds support for Advisory messages that are sent to connected clients which have subscribed to various advisory topics for such things as consumers or producers connecting etc.  See the [Advisory Support](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JMX](http://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html) and configure a MBean that listens to such events, e.g. [JMXConnectionNotification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/remote/JMXConnectionNotification.html).